# How to add username and password in SQL Server 2014 Express database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

How can I put username and password to my database `mydb` so that I can use it to my connection? Just like in MySQL we specify `username = 'root' password = 'root'`.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE LOGIN server_user WITH PASSWORD = '123456789';
GO

USE MYDB;
GO
CREATE USER [server_user] FOR LOGIN [server_user]
GO
ALTER USER [server_user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [server_user]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [server_user]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [server_user]
GO
```

Comment: Hi, what is the difference when we create in the security folder under it there is users table ?is this not the same in your code ?